# C++ summing numbers from a previously printed list

Tags: c++

I've written a program to prompt the user to enter two numbers, and then determine all the prime numbers in the range between the two initial values.  I'd like to sum the total of the found prime numbers.  Does anyone have any pointers?  I"m going to include my current, incorrect, attempt at making this work.  Thanks for your help.

EDIT -- full code is now below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int smallernumber, largernumber, counter, i, IsPrime;
    int sum = 0;


    cout << "Welcome to the Prime Number calculator!  This program will"
        "\ncalculate prime numbers between two values that you'll enter.\n Please enter the the smaller of two values: ";
    cin >> smallernumber;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the larger value ";
    cin >> largernumber;

    for (counter = 2; counter <= largernumber; counter++) {
        IsPrime = 0;

        for (i = 2; i < counter; i++) {

            if (counter % i == 0) {
                IsPrime = 1;


            }
        }

        if (IsPrime == 0 && counter != 1)

            cout << counter << " ";


    }
    for (counter = 2; IsPrime == 0 && counter != 1; counter++) {
        sum += counter;
    }
    cout << "\nthe sum of the prime numbers is: " << sum << endl;

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) even if it won't work, it should compile.

Comment: By providing us incomplete code, we can't help you.!!

Comment: What is not working in the code you provided?

Comment: Add counter to sum after the output.  `cout << counter << " "; sum += counter;` Don't forget {}.

Comment: Pointer: Do a web search for "segmented prime sieve". You will find tons of good ideas.

Comment: "_I"m going to include my current, incorrect, attempt at making this work._" And, what about it, is wrong?

Comment: cin >> smallernumber; you are not using  smallernumber

Comment: Thanks manni66.  Adding that at the end does sum the numbers, but gives an input after every prime number.  Is it possible for it to sum the total just once, after the loop has finished?

Comment: Thanks Hariom, you're right.  it should be counter = smallernumber, not counter = 2

Comment: _but gives an input_ there is no input in +=.

Comment: Off-topic:  you should start your loops at 3 and increment by 2.  All even numbers except 2, are not prime.

Comment: You should try using this modern data type called `bool` for `true` and `false` values.  Using integers is soooo archaic (like 1960's time frame).

Answer (score 1):

Just move `sum += counter` into your if clause:

```
if (IsPrime == 0 && counter != 1) {
    sum += counter;
    cout << counter << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you want I think is that @manni66 talks and also @Daniel Trugman.

```
{
int smallernumber, largernumber, counter, i, IsPrime;
int sum = 0;


std::cout << "Welcome to the Prime Number calculator!  This program will"
    "\n calculate prime numbers between two values that you'll enter.\n Please enter the the smaller of two values: ";
std::cin >> smallernumber;
std::cout << "\n Please enter the larger value ";
std::cin >> largernumber;

for (counter = smallernumber; counter <= largernumber; counter++) 
{
    IsPrime = 0;

    for (i = 2; i < counter; i++) {
        if (counter % i == 0) {
            IsPrime = 1;
        }
    }

    if (IsPrime == 0 && counter != 1)
    {
        std::cout << counter << " ";
        sum += counter;
    }

}
std::cout << "\nthe sum of the prime numbers is: " << sum << "\n";
}
```